# Flutter Call REST API WITHOUT AUTH ALWAYS RETURN 401

Tags: flutter, api, rest, http-status-code-401

I am new to flutter and currently doing some testing on flutter sample code (Form App). I am trying to change the URI to my existing login REST API (which tested with postman and working fine). But it's always return result.statusCode == 401 when called from flutter apps. Any advices and suggestions are welcome and highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'sign_in_http.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class FormData {
  String? email;
  String? password;

  FormData({
    this.email,
    this.password,
  });

  factory FormData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$FormDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FormDataToJson(this);
}

class SignInHttpDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  final http.Client? httpClient;

  const SignInHttpDemo({
    this.httpClient,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SignInHttpDemo> createState() => _SignInHttpDemoState();
}

class _SignInHttpDemoState extends State<SignInHttpDemo> {
  FormData formData = FormData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sign in Form'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        child: Scrollbar(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ...[
                  TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: 'Your email address',
                      labelText: 'Email',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      formData.email = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      labelText: 'Password',
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      formData.password = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('Sign in'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // Use a JSON encoded string to send
                      try {
                        var result = await widget.httpClient!.post(
                            Uri.parse(
                                'https://service.xxx.xxx/api/serv/UserLogin'),
                            body: json.encode(formData.toJson()),
                            headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'});

                        if (result.statusCode == 200) {
                          _showDialog('Successfully signed in.');
                        } else if (result.statusCode == 401) {
                          _showDialog('Unable to sign in.');
                        } else {
                          _showDialog(
                              'Something went wrong. Please try again.');
                        }
                      } catch (err) {
                        print(err.toString());
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ].expand(
                  (widget) => [
                    widget,
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 24,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog(String message) {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(message),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this postmen's suggested code?
Like this...
click here
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpgU4.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSgBB.png)

Comment: yes. I got the replied with Status Code=200 and user details in JSon. {
    "email" : "a@a.com",    
    "password" : "12345"
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).